# Access a document interms of its fields value in Firestore Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I try to write a cloud function which should trigger when user's location change.

---

### Problem

There are two types of user. One ise `Patient` and the other is `Relative`. `Patient` has a list of `relatives` and `Relative` has a list of `patients`.

Both users have location field. `relatives` and `patients` lists have `name`, `email`, and `location` for each `Patient` and `Relative`, respectively.

So I want to update `relatives` and `patients` lists, as long as `Relative` or `Patient` change own `location`.

For example, X is a `Patient` and Y is a `Relative`. In Y's `patients` list, he has `Patient` X's infos, `name`, `email`, `location`. Once X changes his location, it should also be changed in `Relative`'s `patients` list.

**Note:** if a `Patient` is in a `Relative`'s `relatives` list. Then `Relative` has that `Patient` in his `patients` list. Both `Patient` and `Relative` has each others in their lists.

---

### What have I tried

I've tried to get user `email` when onUpdate is triggered in `users` collection. Let's imagine I am `Relative`. And when I change my location, with help of `patients` list, I will search each `Patient`and change my location their `relatives` list.

I can access my email and location. But I cannot get every `Patient`'s `email` in `patients` list.

Can someone help me to achieve that functionality that I talked about above?

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();


exports.UpdateLocations = functions.firestore.document("users/{userID}").onUpdate((change, context) => {
    const userEmail = change.after.data().email;
    const prevLocation = change.before.data().location;
    const currentLocation = change.after.data().location;


    if (prevLocation === currentLocation) return;

    // Here I want to get this user's patients or relatives list. Then store emails in a List.
    // Then search emails, and get patients or relatives list. 
    // With my email, update my current location in patients or relatives list.


});
```

---

How can I achieve this functionality? Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your database structure as you haven't attached any image, so I have assumed some things. I believe that both `Relative` and `Patient` are in the collection `users` with seemingly no way to distinguish them. I assumed that they have either a `relatives` or `patients` sub-collection with that exact name/id.

I have used a [collection groups query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) in order to retrieve all the users on every `relatives` sub-collection where their email was `userEmail`. I have then updated those documents with the location in `currentLocation`.

This will update all the users inside `relatives` that have the email `userEmail`. In case you want to do the same with the sub-collection `patients` you just have to change the key in `collectionGroup`.

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();


exports.UpdateLocations = functions.firestore.document("users/{userID}").onUpdate((change, context) => {
    const userEmail = change.after.data().email;
    const prevLocation = change.before.data().location;
    const currentLocation = change.after.data().location;

    if (prevLocation === currentLocation) return;

    let relativesQuery = db.collectionGroup('relatives').where('email', '==', userEmail);
    relativesQuery.get().then((querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.forEach((document) => {
            document.ref.update({location: currentLocation});
        });
    });

});
```

Disclaimer, I haven't tested this code as I'm not sure of your structure, but it should still be a good starting point to use `collectionGroup` instead of many nested queries.